# "Centering" images with bootstrap's grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Explanation

I trying to "center" 3 images with Bootstrap's grid class `col-lg-3` (>=1200px), but for some reason, when using a 273x303 image, it doesn't center; however, it does with a 670x670 one, as you can see in the code below.

Am I doing anything wrong? I got kinda confused since 670x670 works great.

### Code

**273x303**

You can also see it's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sstpz5q/embedded/result/).

```css
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
  color: black !important;
}

h4, span {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>273x303</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <section class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">
                        <h2>273x303</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 1</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 1</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 2</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 2</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 3</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 3</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**670x670**

You can also see it's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbzc603m/embedded/result/).

```css
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
  color: black !important;
}

h4, span {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>670x670</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <section class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">
                        <h2>670x670</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/LBFo66H.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 1</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 1</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/LBFo66H.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 2</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 2</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/LBFo66H.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 3</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 3</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, 
Luiz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize the `.center-block` class in bootstrap on the images to center them. That will apply a left/right margin of `auto`, which will center the block element that results from using `.img-responsive`

```css
.main {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
}

h4,
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">
        <h2>273x303</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
        <h4>testing title 1</h4>
        <span>testing subtitle 1</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
        <img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
        <h4>testing title 2</h4>
        <span>testing subtitle 2</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
        <img class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
        <h4>testing title 3</h4>
        <span>testing subtitle 3</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Luiz np. Just FYI, it's better practice to utilize bootstrap's classes than it is to modify them with manual CSS. It makes for cleaner, more maintainable code. I'm not encouraging you to accept my answer or anything instead, but would recommend you utilize their classes in the markup over overwriting functionality with custom CSS when it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Class `.img-responsive` from Bootstrap already sets `display: block`, you can use `margin: 0 auto` to center.

Add this line:

```
.master .img-responsive {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
  color: black !important;
}

h4, span {
  color: red !important;
}

.master .img-responsive {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>273x303</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <section class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">
                        <h2>273x303</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 1</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 1</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 2</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 2</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 3</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 3</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in re: `.center-block` +1

Answer (score 2):

```
.img-responsive {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sstpz5q/2/

Comment: Thank you!! Since vanloc answered before, I'm accepting his answer, but your answer solves as well, thank you again!!

Comment: of course, no problem, as long as you got your problem solved is most important thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `display: initial;` to the `.img-responsive` class. The snippet below has been updated.

NOTE: The use of `!important` is not required.

```css
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
  color: black !important;
}

h4, span {
  color: red !important;
}

.img-responsive {
   display: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>273x303</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <section class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">
                        <h2>273x303</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 1</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 1</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 2</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 2</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 master text-center">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/3Eqr1Gf.png" alt="Blog Post">
                        <h4>testing title 3</h4>
                        <span>testing subtitle 3</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Since vanloc answered before, I'm accepting his answer, but your answer solves as well, thank you again!!